# C# Nullable Reference Types: can this function accept a dictionary with both nullable and non-nullable value without overriding null checking?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types, c#-9.0

I am trying to write a function that will convert a Dictionary's `TryGet` into a "lookup" object in C# 9.0. The (simplified version of) code I have so far looks like this:

```cs
class C1
{
    [Test]
    public void METHOD()
    {
        var lookupValue1 = Lookup(new Dictionary<string, string?>(), "a");
        var lookupValue2 = Lookup(new Dictionary<string, string>(), "a");
    }

    public LookupValue<TV> Lookup<TK, TV>(Dictionary<TK, TV?> d, TK key) 
        where TK : notnull
        where TV : notnull
    {
        if (d.TryGetValue(key, out var result))
        {
            return new LookupValue<TV>(result);
        }
        else
        {
            return new LookupValue<TV>(default);
        }
    }

    public record LookupValue<T>(T? Value) where T : notnull;
}
```

But this code won't compile, specifically, this line: `var lookupValue2 = Lookup(new Dictionary<string, string>(), "a");`

I know I can override the null reference checking by using a `!` operator: `var lookupValue2 = Lookup(new Dictionary<string, string>()!, "a");` but this is supposed to be a public API and I son't want the users of the API to  have to do this. Also, I know I can create two methods named differently in the same class or methods named the same in separate classes, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Is there any way to make this `Lookup` function accept a dictionary with a nullable value type as well as one with non-nullable value type and preserve the signature of the `LookupValue` record?

Comment: Unfortunately c# keeps digging the [null hole even deeper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare&ved=2ahUKEwj25bWRiITyAhUGhVwKHeduDngQFjABegQIHhAC&usg=AOvVaw0-HLzXMtppqSQCF_4OdQ5R). What you really need is a way to describe an [optional type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) and unwrap it.

Comment: This kind of problem was introduced with nullable reference types. In C#8 it wouldn't exist.

Comment: You don't need your `LookupValue` type: it is redundant. Why do you think you need it? (Also you'll end-up confusing people with Linq's `ILookup` which is something else entirely).

Comment: Your `Lookup` method should accept an `IReadOnlyDictionary`, not a `Dictionary`.

Comment: `return new LookupValue<TV>(default);` doing this **is a very bad idea** when `TV` is a struct, because there's no indication that the lookup failed and that the value is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written a function which demands a Dictionary whose values are nullable. In other words, the value for a key might be null, and it's allowed to set a null value for a key. So there's no reasonable way for such a function to accept a Dictionary whose values are non-nullable.

Instead, you could consider making the function accept a dictionary with *any* kind of value type. You can do this by removing the `notnull` constraint on `TV` and removing the nullable annotation in the type argument to the dictionary type.

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

```cs
class C1
{
    [Test]
    public void METHOD()
    {
        var lookupValue1 = Lookup(new Dictionary<string, string?>(), "a");
        var lookupValue2 = Lookup(new Dictionary<string, string>(), "a");
    }

    public LookupValue<TV?> Lookup<TK, TV>(Dictionary<TK, TV> d, TK key) 
        where TK : notnull
    {
        if (d.TryGetValue(key, out var result))
        {
            return new LookupValue<TV?>(result);
        }
        else
        {
            return new LookupValue<TV?>(default);
        }
    }

    public record LookupValue<T>(T Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer explained why it's impossible to get what I want. I don't want to remove the `notnull` constraint, so my second best option will be to create two differently named methods - one accepting `Dictionary<T, V>` and another accepting `Dictionary<T,V?>`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but requires an overload, another generic parameter (which cannot be inferred) and a cast in the code. Still, this might be a better option sometimes than another method with a different name if the nullable use case is rare.

```cs
class C1
{
  [Test]
  public void Method()
  {
    var lookup1 = new Dictionary<string, string?>().Lookup("a");
    var lookup2 = new Dictionary<string, string>().Lookup<string, string, string>("a");
  }
}

public static class DictExtensions
{
  public static LookupValue<TV> Lookup<TK, TV>(this IDictionary<TK, TV> d, TK key)
    where TK : notnull
    where TV : notnull
  {
    return d.Lookup<TK, TV, TV>(key);
  }

  public static LookupValue<TR> Lookup<TK, TV, TR>(this IDictionary<TK, TV> d, TK key)
    where TK : notnull
    where TR : notnull, TV
  {
    if (d.TryGetValue(key, out var result))
    {
      return new LookupValue<TR>((TR?)result);
    }
    else
    {
      return new LookupValue<TR>(default);
    }
  }

  public record LookupValue<T>(T? Value) where T : notnull;
}
```